# DB content not coming into tinyMCE textarea

Tags: php, html, tinymce, rich-text-editor

My tinyMCE editor is showing up just fine, but in the form I have a select box and according to what you choose, the textarea is filled with content accordingly.

Like if I choose PHP, then the description for PHP comes into the textarea. It works without tinyMCE, but when I add tinyMCE, nothing shows up in the textarea.

Comment: Are you testing it on FireFox perhaps?

Comment: You should split this question into two individual ones. This way you will have more chances on being found by someone who will be able to help you. For example I do not understand your second problem, but I know the answer to the first one.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa i tried on chrome as well

Comment: @JahanzebKhan: Forgive me, but even that you haven't asked me to edit your question, I am pretty sure that in this form it will be more helpful to all the users. You can always rollback my change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyMCE does not display the content of the textarea **in real-time**. It reads the content on start, and saves it at the end of the work. All the edit work takes place in an `iframe` element, created on the fly by Tiny. If you update the `textarea`, you must ask TinyMCE to refresh itself.

In a few minutes I will look up the exact method for you. (It was long time ago when I was using TinyMCE, so I forgot the method names.)

*[few minutes have passed..]*

Look at the documentation: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_load/save_with_Ajax_in_TinyMCE

You just need to call [setContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent) method on the TinyMCE editor, instead of (or in addition to) setting the new text in the `textarea`.

Comment: THANKS! It works! BTW, what did I do wrong in my question that I got -2 rep? Please tell me so I dont make such a mistake again!

Comment: Well, now when I click the submit button nothing happens... there are 2 forms, add blog, edit blog, in add blog there is no dropdown list to fill content, but some reason its not doing anything when i submit that, and on the edit blog form, there is a dropdown list and using the setContent method, the textarea is filled up, but it doesnt submit after applying the setContent method

Comment: About what you did wrong in the question: I believe the problem comes from the fact that you might consider StackOverflow being like a forum. It is not, so usually there are no "discussions". You just ask a single question, and you receive answers. If you have multiple problems, you should ask few independent questions, probably _mentioning_ your other questions as being "possibly related". I believe that was the reason for downvotes. I believe that now you may want to rollback the last edit to this question, and ask a new one (or two new ones). I can edit this question for you, if you want.

Comment: If the question is clear, and matches the answers _(yeah, it should be the other way round :-)_, then the question may receive further upvotes over time.

Comment: About your "submit" problem: I believe that you might need to use `getContent` method to retrieve back the edited text before submit, but I am not sure. Anyway, you definitely should ask this as another question - this one already has an answer, thus almost nobody will find it. A new question always attracts users.

Answer (score 0):

with tiny mce sometimes it dependes the plugins that you in the Init.
Try Removing all the plugins and add one by one and see if this helps you in finding a better solution for this.

Some plugins like the media can strip and not allow tags in the text area, so the textarea is empty if tiny mce doens't allow that tags, or add valid_elemens:'*[*]' and try if it shows something.

Good luck